# Полупрозрачность всей страницы когда выводится картинка-прелоадер

Tags: css

Как заставить браузер установить полупрозрачность `opacity: .5;` для всего контента на странице, в случае вывода картинки-прелоадера?
Картинка выводится добавлением свойства `display: block` для класса `preloader`, который по умолчанию скрыт.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проще сделать наоборот. Поверх всей страницы положить слой с размерами 100%х100%, белой заливкой и opacity: 0.5

```
.fade {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0; left: 0;
    right: 0; bottom: 0;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}
```

UPD: Вы можете прямо на этом слое по центру показать свой прелоадер, проблем с `opacity` не будет, так как используется rgba цвет, а не глобальный `opacity`. Вот так:

```
.fade {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0; left: 0;
    right: 0; bottom: 0;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5) url(preloader.gif) no-repeat 50% 50%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Помести всё содержимое страницы в дополнительный div и меняй ему opacity.

Preloader при этом будет лежать рядом в body и на него opacity влиять не будет.

Comment: Можно приложить пример такой реализации, имею в виду смена `opacity`, когда запускается прелоадер. `div.preloader` получил `display: block;` теперь следовало бы сменить `opacity` для `div.main`, к примеру.